# How do you solve this problem regarding aligning divs next to each other?

Tags: css, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Aligning divs next to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498212/aligning-divs-next-to-each-other)

I want this design:

```
DIV1: auto-size DIV2: 160px
divnumberonediv divtwo
divnumberonediv divtwo
divnumberonediv divtwo
divnumberonediv divtwo
divnumberonediv divtwo
divnumberonediv divtwo
```

How do I solve this problem? I've tried stuff like floating left & right, but I just can't get them on the same line.

I want the div 2 to always be there, and the div1 to have a max-width of 40em, but resize to allow the div 2 to show at all times if its necessary.

My CSS code:

```
#mainbulk {
 padding: 1.5em 2% 1.5em .5em;
}
#ads {
 width: 7.5em;
 float: left;
 display: table-cell;
 padding: 0 0 0 2em;
}
#textcontent {
 width: 70%;
 float: left;
 display: table-cell;
}
```

and HTML

```
<div id="mainbulk">
 <div id="textcontent">
  <p>This is the most amazing site in the world. It has a very nice design, and is perfect for everything. If there's something that this site can't do, then nothing can do it, but I'd suggest to try all of this site's features before complaining.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="ads" align="right">
    ads would, hypothetically, be placed here if this were actually an actual website.
    </div>
</div>
```

---

I'm encountering this problem:

http://www.screencast-o-matic.com/watch/c6lrXsXyQ

---

Full source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Frotly</title>
<style type="text/css">
body, html {
    font-size: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#intro {
    border: 0;
    text-align: inherit;
    width: inherit;
}

#content {
    max-width: 50em;
    margin: 0 0 0 .7em;
}
#header {
    background-image: url(images/frotly.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 6.25em;
}
#menu {
    text-align: left;
}
#mainbulk {
    text-align: left;
}
#menu a {
    height: 1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0.15em .6em;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    margin: 0 .5em;
    border-color: #000;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px; /*Mozilla*/
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;

}
#menu a:link{
    border: px solid black;
    background: url(images/menubg2.gif) repeat-x;
}
#menu a:hover {
    background: url(images/menubginv.gif) repeat-x;
}
#mainbulk {
    padding: 1.5em 2% 1.5em .5em;
}
#ads {
    width: 7.5em;
    float: left;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 0 0 2em;
}
#textcontent {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    display: table-cell;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="content">
<div id="intro">
    <div id="header">

    </div>
    <div id="menu">
        <a href="#">Page 2</a><a href="#">Page 3</a><a href="#">Page 4</a><a href="#">Page 5</a><a href="#">Page 6</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="mainbulk">
    <div id="textcontent">
        <p>Frotly is the most amazing site in the world. It has a very nice design, and is perfect for everything. If there's something that Frotly can't do, then nothing can do it, but I'd suggest to try all of Frotly's features before complaining.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="ads">
    sdjafjhdj fg dfg sdf sadf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdfa sd hgilehri hergiuesrh iofdshoiers f vpaeirg 9owaej waeoioje raoaednae dnirefn oeh råo hwog heirhg oesnr ieharg eanr poaergo neriuhg neiarginea rer gr.
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please refine your original question to provide more information, or further clarify the problem. Ideally explaining why the current answers are unsatisfactory. Posting new questions has (at least) two side effects: first, it simply adds further noise to the system; and second, and far more importantly, it irritates people enough that they almost immediately vote to close as an exact duplicate.

Comment: @David Thomas --- it's all explained in the accompanying video. http://www.screencast-o-matic.com/watch/c6lrXsXyQ I added that to the other question after people stopped visiting it.

Comment: you can edit the title of your question and add a comment to let people know its been updated. Don't re-post questions as people will just close it instead of answering it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#mainbulk { width: 960px; }
```

Set the width of the main container, or use `min-width`

Comment: It is in there already, I just added a bit of the site to the question. Also I don't like px, prefer em.

Comment: I think its because you're using max-width, try adding a min-width too